# Stuck on integration by parts question

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, integration-by-parts

[image]

Here's what I have so far, but I'm stuck with what to do after this

[image]

Comment: The notation here is throwing me off a bit. What book is this from?

Comment: It's not a published book, what is throwing you off?

Comment: For instance pulling $f(\tau)$ outside the delimiters of the integral.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For any compactly supported function $\phi$ you get
$$
\int_{-∞}^∞ f(s)\phi'(x-s)\,ds=\left[f(s)·(-ϕ(x−s))\right]_{-∞}^∞+\int_{-∞}^∞ f'(s)\phi(x-s)\,ds
\\=\int_{-∞}^∞ f'(s)\phi(x-s)\,ds
$$
so that
$$
\int_{-∞}^∞ f(s)\frac{d^n}{ds^n}\phi(x-s)\,ds
=(-1)^n\int_{-∞}^∞ f(s)\phi^{(n)}(x-s)\,ds
\\=(-1)^n\int_{-∞}^∞ f^{(n)}(s)\phi(x-s)\,ds
$$
and for $ϕ\to\delta$ as distributions the last term converges to $(-1)^nf^{(n)}(x)$.

Answer (score 1):

Proceeding formally, we have

$$\begin{align}
\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(\tau)\,\frac{d^2\,\delta(t-\tau)}{d\tau^2}\,d\tau&=\int_{-\infty}^\infty \left(\frac{d}{d\tau}\left(f(\tau)\frac{d\,\delta(t-\tau)}{d\tau}\right)-\frac{df(\tau)}{d\tau}\frac{d\,\delta(t-\tau)}{d\tau}\right)\,d\tau\\\\
&=-\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{df(\tau)}{d\tau}\frac{d\,\delta(t-\tau)}{d\tau}\,d\tau\\\\
&=-\int_{-\infty}^\infty \left(\frac{d}{d\tau}\left(\frac{df(\tau)}{d\tau}\delta(t-\tau)\right)-\frac{d^2f(\tau)}{d\tau^2}\delta(t-\tau)\right)\,d\tau\\\\
&=\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{d^2f(\tau)}{d\tau^2}\delta(t-\tau)\\\\
&=\frac{d^2f(t)}{dt^2}
\end{align}$$